# BibLaTeX: change how referencing is done and replace URL tag in citations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using \parencite and it's working but I'd like to know if it's possible to:

1 - Add a comma between author and year. From (World Health Organization 1986) to (World Health Organization, 1986)

2 - Use an acronym (or manual substitution to write anything) in the referencing even if in the bibliography it's not an acronym. From (World Health Organization, 1986) to (WHO, 1986)

And:

3- How to replace "URL" with "Disponível em" in the citations in the bibliography.

Example: From

"World Health Organization (1986). The Ottawa Charter for Health Promotion. URL: blabla (acedido em 31/03/2015)."

to

"World Health Organization (1986). The Ottawa Charter for Health Promotion. Disponível em: blabla (acedido em 31/03/2015).

4- To show repeated authors.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{WHO1,
    author = {World{\ }Health{\ }Organization},
    title = {The Ottawa Charter for Health Promotion},
    year = {1986},
    url = {http://www.who.int/healthpromotion/conferences/previous/ottawa/en/},
    urldate = {2015-03-31},
}
@online{WHO2,
    author = {World{\ }Health{\ }Organization},
    title = {The Ottawa Charter for Health Promotion},
    year = {1987},
    url = {http://www.who.int/healthpromotion/conferences/previous/ottawa/en/},
    urldate = {2015-03-31},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\parencite{WHO1}
...
\parencite{WHO2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

Desired results:

(World Health Organization, 1986) ... (WHO, 1987)

Referências

World Health Organization (1986). The Ottawa Charter for Health Promotion.
Disponível em: blabla (visited on 03/31/2015).

World Health Organization (1987). The Ottawa Charter for Health Promotion. Disponível em: blabla (visited on 03/31/2015).

(I had to use blabla because I'm limited to two links)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a comma between name and year in citation labels:

```
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\addspace}
```

To use a different author name in citations, add

```
shortauthor = {WHO}
```

to the relevant bibliography entries.

If you want author names to be repeated in the bibliography rather than replaced by lines after the first instance, pass `biblatex` the package option `dashed=false`. [Thanks to [jon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300751/biblatex-change-how-referencing-is-done-and-replace-url-tag-in-citations/300758?noredirect=1#comment728482_300758) for the explanation of (4).]

For the label, you *should*, I *think*, be able to say

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{portuguese}{url={Disponível em}}
```

However, this does not appear to work, while adding `urlseen={been there, done that}`, although undesirable on other grounds, does have the merit of appearing to work.

So it seems that you must redefine the field format because this field does not use the `url` `bibstring` but, instead, uses `\mkbibacro{URL}`.  One way would be to use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
```

which is modified to use the `bibstring` in the same way as similar field formats for things like `urlseen`. However, it beats me what the `bibstring` `url` is meant to do in this case, so this seems more of a hack than a correct solution.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{WHO1,
    author = {{World Health Organization}},
    shortauthor = {WHO},
    title = {The {Ottawa} Charter for Health Promotion},
    year = {1986},
    url = {http://www.who.int/healthpromotion/conferences/previous/ottawa/en/},
    urldate = {2015-03-31},
}
@online{WHO2,
    author = {{World Health Organization}},
    shortauthor = {WHO},
    title = {The {Ottawa} Charter for Health Promotion},
    year = {1987},
    url = {http://www.who.int/healthpromotion/conferences/previous/ottawa/en/},
    urldate = {2015-03-31},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[portuguese]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\addspace}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{portuguese}{%
  url={Disponível em},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\begin{document}
\parencite{WHO1}

\parencite{WHO2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So this is only a partial answer. (Has anybody mentioned the 'one question per question' rule? Helps to keep the site tidy....)

[image: demo of 3 bits & 1 hack]

Comment: I think (4) is about not using (let's call it) the 'ibid dash' so that the author/editor/<etc.> is always printed.

Comment: For (3): I don't think it's a string, but a 'field format' thing: so `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Disponível em\addcolon\space\url{#1}}`

Comment: @jon Oh, so just `dashed=false` for the first bit?

Comment: And for (4) you could `\renewbibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}` so it always uses the second argument, which would prevent `\bibnamedash` from getting used. (I have not extensively tested how this would interact with citations, but it seems reasonable enough a way forward.) ... **OR**, as you say, used `dashed=false`..!

Comment: @jon Thanks. I've updated with the first point.

Comment: @jon The `authoryear` style offers `dashed` as a standard option. No need to reinvent that particular wheel ;).

Comment: @jon Do the nodes in the change log mean that they made `url` a string but then reverted it, do you think? I don't understand the second change described there along with the addition of `urlfrom`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Using `\DeclareFieldFormat` works for me. (But note that I'm not fully up to date with `biblatex`. I have a semi-functioning style for the (horrid) *McGill Guide* [which only caters to the subset I currently need], and I'm concerned about the most recent changes to the name stuff, so I'm not updating until certain projects are done.)

Comment: @jon Please see edit. But this does not seem right to me.... Well, the change log comments are from 2013....

Comment: Hmm, in my (outdated) `biblatex.def`, the field formats don't use `\bibstring`s at all, but a fancy `\mkbibacro` (for URL, ISSN, etc.). I'd say your way could work for internationalization, but it would depend on what language settings are used in the `biblatex` options (and what the `url` string is defined as for the utilized languages). If one just wants an unchanging phrase, you can hardcode it in like in my earlier comment.

Comment: @jon `biblatex.def` doesn't even exist anymore ;). However, `url` does use `\mkbibacro`. I adapted it to 'look like' the similar field formats around it. For example `urldate` uses `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}`. So using a `bibstring` here seems more in keeping with the overall approach than hard-coding something when nothing else but acronyms seem to be hard-coded. (Presumably those are assumed to be international already.)

Comment: I prefer the string approach, I think. Now I'm just worried about the update. It has taken a long time to learn how to navigate the `biblatex` cosmos and it's starting to sound like at least some of my maps will no longer be reliable....

Comment: @jon There is a `biblatex_.def` where I found this, but there are a bunch of changes which are new new, I think. (As in, `biblatex.def` was there last time I looked....) `biblatex1.sty` and `biblatex2.sty` seem to be gone, too. I guess that `biblatex_.sty` and `biblatex_legacy.sty` are similar, but the `_.def` file, I suspect is now Biber-specific, though I haven't confirmed this suspicion yet. But there's a `biblatex_legacy.def` which suggests it.  Still uses `bibstring`s, though.

Comment: I made all four questions at the same time thinking it'd help. I can see how it can be worse, next time if I have several questions I'll stick to the 'one question per question' rule. Thanks to all for the help! It really helps a lot with the thesis deadline and my limited LaTeX knowledge.

Comment: @JCML No problem. It makes it easier for other people to find relevant questions when there's one per question. And it helps if people know the answer to one of them but not the others, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to change the key "urlseen", that states the, so the command you should give is:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{portuguese}{urlseen={Disponível em}}
```